# JPA Derived Column value based on Identity column

Tags: hibernate, jpa

JPA 2.0 (Hibernate 4.2.4.Final/Spring 3.2.8.Release) / Mysql 5.6

For a managed entity E w/ auto-generated primary key e.g.

```
...
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@Column
private String foo;

@Version
@Column(name="mod_date")
private Timetamp modDate;
...
```

foo needs to equal :{id}: for legacy reasons.  E.g. if id was 204, foo would be ":204:"
For this to happen w/in a transaction this is what works

```
em.persist(e);
em.detach(e);
e = em.find(e.getId());
e.setFoo(":" + e.getId() + ":");
...
```

Is there a better way of computing a derived column where the value depends on the generated Id ?
Without the above hack i.e. directly updating the column after persist results in a org.hibernate.StaleObjectException. I see this happening in unit tests (in fact I can step through the unit test code and can repro the exception which rules out the multi thread issue usually associated w/ StaleObjectException

Comment: Setting the mod_date column definition to be timestamp(3) in mysql got rid of the StaleObjectException which had led me down the wrong path.  Now using @PostPersist and it works great. Thx Alan Hay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JPA PostPersist Event Listener to handle this.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@Column
private String foo;

@PostPersist
public void onSave(){
    foo = ":" + id + ":";
}
```

From the JPA 2 specification:

> The PostPersist and PostRemove callback methods are invoked for an
>   entity after the entity has been made persistent or removed. These
>   callbacks will also be invoked on all entities to which these
>   operations are cascaded. The PostPersist and PostRemove methods will
>   be invoked after the database insert and delete operations
>   respectively. These database operations may occur directly after the
>   persist, merge, or remove operations have been invoked or they may
>   occur directly after a flush operation has occurred (which may be at
>   the end of the transaction). **Generated primary key values are
>   available in the PostPersist method.**

Comment: That's exactly what I had tried but unfortunately that was failing because of the StaleObjectException. (Mea culpa - should have mentioned that in the original post)  Turned out that was an issue w/how timestamps are handled in MySQL 5.5 vs 5.6.  See revised post. Have gone back to doing exactly what you suggested

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to simply compute the Column value upon loading, using @Formula:

```
@Formula(value="':'||id||':'")
private String foo;
```

Comment: We're trying to stick to JPA only syntax. Believe this is a Hibernate specific implementation

Comment: Yes, it's Hibernate specific. But in the same time it's a very efficient way of solving your issue.

Comment: Not disagreeing with you at all on the efficiency or terseness of the solution. Just trying to be strict about adhereing to the JPA standard and not using vendor specific extensions. Its whole another debate of will we ever switch away from Hibernate to say TopLink :)

Comment: I understand your requirements. I am still waiting to find a project that switched JPA providers.

Comment: IMESHO, its nice to stick to specs. If I provide an app, the runtime is not my business. The consumer should be able to deploy however e.g. Toplink/EclipseLink within WebSphere/GlassFish.  I'm pretty sure there are folks who have switched providers for performance / bug reasons.  Specs are good - no ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interceptor for this requirement, see below example:

Let's say you have an entity called `Student` with properties `id` (acts as an identifier) and `foo`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String foo;
    // Setters & Getters
}
```

Now you can create an interceptor that extends Empty Interceptor of hibernate and overrides the `onSave` method that sets the `foo` property with value as `:{id}` like this:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.hibernate.CallbackException;
import org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor;
import org.hibernate.type.Type;

public class MyInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state,
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException {
        System.out.println("Entered onSave : class - " + entity.getClass());
        if (entity instanceof Student) {
            Student s = (Student) entity;
            System.out.println("class:" + entity.getClass() + " , id: "+s.getId());
            s.setFoo(":"+id);
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Now you need to tell hibernate to use this interceptor like this:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().setInterceptor( new LogInterceptor() );
configuration.configure();
```