# Derive NOT NULL column value based on Generated ID column

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, h2

I basically have the same question as [JPA Derived Column value based on Identity column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27010529/4740715), but with the additional requirement that the column `foo` is NOT NULL.

I tried using the @PostPersist annotation but a null constraint violated exception is thrown.

Comment: Huh?   Please explain better, and with examples.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to persist foo atrribute with null value when it should never be null. Understand that `@PostPersist` is invoked after the object is persisted successfully, which is not your case. This means that it is not possible to save the entity to only then popular the foo field. YOU MUST TO DO THIS BEFORE PERSIST OPERATION.